# How to calculate bottom offset of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I have already tried with below code.

```
var $el = $('#gallery-view');
$el.position().top + $el.outerHeight(true);
```

Comment: And what went wrong with your code? It actually depends on all the ancestor styling, up to the body, so it would help if you provided the HTML too :)

Comment: @Amit : i added below the image

Comment: No you didn't. Read [ask].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well that depends on what your container is.

eg. If you want to calculate distance between your div's bottom and the window then it would be something like this

```
var delta =  $(window).height() - ( $('#div').offset().top + $('#div').height() );
```

eg. If you want to calculate relative to a container div then it would be something like this.

```
var delta =  ( $('#container').offset().top + $('#container').height() ) - ( $('#div').offset().top + $('#div').height() );
```